# Is $f(x)=x|x|$ differentiable everywhere?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

When $f$ is a function $\mathbf{R}$ to $R$. I know $\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=
\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{x^2}{x}=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=
\lim_{x \to 0-}\frac{-x^2}{x}=0$, but $|x|$ is not differentiable everywhere, so I'm doubting myself.

Comment: It's differentiable everywhere. Your intuition is mistaken.

Comment: A follow-up exercise: is it twice differentiable everywhere?

Comment: @par no because the limits would then be 2 and -2 :).

Comment: Product of differentiable functions is differentiable, but that doesn't mean product of not differentiable ones is not differentiable

Comment: You could've attempted to perform product rule, after which you would get:  $$x\left(\frac d{dx}|x|\right)+|x|$$, then we see that as $x\to0$, the first term tends to 0 while the second term tends to 0.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is differentiable everywhere, but it does not have a *second* derivative at $x=0$.

One way to see this is to use the equivalent definition

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 x^2,  & x\ge 0 \\[2ex]
 -x^2, & x< 0 \\ 
\end{cases}$$

The derivative of each piece (the limit on the left piece) at/approaching $x=0$ is zero, so the derivative at $x=0$ is indeed zero. This graph should show that the first derivative is defined as zero at $x=0$ but the second derivative is undefined there.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It should be clear that $f$ is differentiable for $x\neq 0$.

For $x=0$, we have
$\lim_{x \to 0} { f(x)-f(0) \over x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} |x| = 0$, hence $f$
is differentiable at $x=0$ with derivative zero.